# Getting the original command invocation from /proc/self

Tags: linux, process, proc

I'm trying to run some startup code in all procesess via the dynamic linker.

The code should do stuff based on the zeroth argument of the process.
I'm getting the arguments from `/proc/self/cmdline` (if you know of better way to access them outside of main, please tell), however this has one problem:

Scripts get their shebang (without the `#!`) as their zeroth argument and in that case I'm interested in the next argument. But how can I differentiate interpreted processes from native ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detail which you are extracting from `/proc/self/status` is found in `/proc/self/comm` (without scripting).

For the intended question: to determine which processes are *interpreted* and which are *native*, you cannot do this without knowing which processes are intended to be *interpreters*.  After all, any process can rename itself via an `exec` call, using whatever it likes to the resulting process's argument list.  You could *guess* by comparing `/proc/self/exe` (which points to the executable) to the argument list, but that would only be a guess, since there are examples where a non-interpreter renames its descendants just to make their use more apparent.

Further reading:

- [Getting Process Invocations: The Hard Way](http://www.schwertly.com/2014/12/getting-process-invocations-the-hard-way/)
- [The /proc filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)
- [Howto change a UNIX process and child process name by modifying argv[0]](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/processname.html)

Answer (score 0):

It appears processes get `Name`s in

```
</proc/self/status |grep '^Name'
```

and the name appears to be the `basename` of the real zeroth argument.

(I'll keep the question here in case someone provides a better answer).